# Working of size() method of list in java

Tags: java

I have 2 pieces of code and first part is here

```
int count = myArrayList.size();

for (int a =0; a< count; a++) {
    //any calculation
}
```

Second part of the code is

```
 for (int a =0; a< myArrayList.size(); a++) {
    //any calculation
}
```

in both piece I am iterating over myArrayList (this is ArrayList) size but in first part I am calculating size then iterating it means the method size is being called only once but on the other hand in second part whenever it iterates it calculates the size first then then check for size in less than or not.Isn't it long process ?I have seen in many examples in many places (which calculate size on every iteration).

**My questions:**

1. Isn't it long process? (talking about second part)
2. what is best practice first or second?
3. which is efficient way to perform iteration?
4. myArrayList.size() how this size method works or calculates the size?

EDITION: 
For testing the same thing I wrote programs and calculated the time the code is

```
ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int a =0; a<1000; a++) {
        myArrayList.add(a);
    }


    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

     for (int a =0; a< myArrayList.size(); a++) {
        //any calculation
    }

     long lastTime = System.nanoTime();

     long result = lastTime - startTime;
```

and the result is = 34490 nano seconds

on the other hand

```
ArrayList<Integer> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int a =0; a<1000; a++) {
        myArrayList.add(a);
    }

    long startTIme = System.nanoTime();
    int count = myArrayList.size();

    for (int a =0; a< count; a++) {

    }

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long result = endTime - startTIme;
```

and the result is = 11394 nano seconds

here when calling size() method in every iteration taking much time then without calling it every call.Is this the right way to check the time calculation?

Comment: I am sure that the JVM can cache this value, and not `calculate` for every iteration of the loop.  Also have a look at the `size` method in the java code.

Comment: *"1)Isn't it long process?"* not by a lot; *"2)what is best practice first or second?"* - Neither (or both depending on what you are trying to do), however, you should consider using an enhanced loop or `Iterator` instead; *"3)which is efficient way to perform iteration?"* - Use an `Iterator` or enhanced loop; *"4)myArrayList.size()"* - Maintains a variable which represents the number of elements contained within it's backing buffer, so, not much

Comment: @ScaryWombat Hehehe, yeah, but you can remove and add elements from the `ArrayList` and it will effect the termination condition, so it must be getting called on each iteration ;)

Comment: in documentation it is written "it returns the number of element" so I had this question how it implements internally? does it calculate one and caches it ?I was not sure about it

Comment: ArrayList keeps a private variable with its own length. It gets updated when you add to or shorten the list.

Comment: hmm yes now I understand thank you all for providing nice suggestions

Answer (score 3):

1. No. The call is not a "long running" process, the JVM can make function calls quickly.
2. Either is acceptable. Prefer the one that's easier to read. Adding a local reference with a meaningful name can make something easier to read.
3. You might prefer the [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html), but for *readability*<sup>1</sup>. There is no appreciable efficiency difference in your options (or with the `for-each`).
4. The `ArrayList` implementation keeps an internal count (in the OpenJDK implementation, and probably others, that is [`size`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.0size)) and manages the internal array that backs the `List`.

<sup>1<sub>See also [The Developer Insight Series, Part 1: Write Dumb Code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/devinsight-1-139780.html)</sub></sup>

Comment: Re: 2) Unless you need the count or the iteration index in the loop, I would say best practice it to use a for-each loop instead.